# Why do some Apple framework protocols not conform to <NSObject>?

Tags: objective-c, protocols

Many SDK-defined protocols, eg. UITableViewDelegate, conform to the NSObject protocol. Some, like NSFastEnumeration, don't.

Does anyone know why this might be?

All I can think of offhand is that Apple might have anticipated that classes inheriting from a root class other than NSObject (eg. NSProxy) might need to conform to protocols like NSFastEnumeration, but not (for example) UITableViewDelegate. But the reason for the distinction between the two isn't obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegate-type protocols tend to conform to NSObject. More "pure" protocols like NSCopying don't. As for why, my assumption is just because they want protocols like copying, locking and fast enumeration to be as simple as possible, while with delegates you invariably want more standard object features like `respondsToSelector:`.

Comment: Further evidence of this is that even newly created "low level" protocols like `<NSXPCProxyCreating>` do not conform to `<NSObject>`, while much older, but higher-level protocols like `<NSURLProtocolClient>` do. Of course in some ways I'm defining "low level" as "those that don't conform to `<NSObject>`," but in general the philosophy does seem to follow. Compare `<NSXPCProxyCreating>` wich `<NSXPCListenerDelegate>` for instance, and think of what kinds of objects each might be.

Comment: @RobNapier: I think a slightly better definition of "low-level" would be "defines a certain behavior an object can implement," while the "high-level" protocols are more like "defines a role in an application that an object can fill." That's kind of what I was trying to get at with the word "pure" — they just specify a uniform way of talking to an object that has certain traits, rather than defining a place in a larger design.

Comment: That makes good sense. The (micro) behaviour vs (macro) role-specifying distinction is a plausible one. I've edited the question to make it a bit more general. Given that the classes conforming to NSCopying et al will in practise nearly universally informally implement <NSObject> by inheritance, it seems the distinction is primarily a matter of documentation. It's odd then that Apple doesn't call this out in some way.